# Issue with make and sudo make in Linux kernel module compilation

Tags: linux-kernel, sudo, kernel-modules, make

I am currently working on a simple Linux kernel module and have encountered an issue related to running make and sudo make commands. Here's the content of my Makefile:

```
obj-m := main.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

When I run make as a regular user, the compilation process works perfectly. However, when I try sudo make, the $(PWD) command seems to fail, resulting in an error. the pwd is an environment variable which exits even as in the shell as a root user and the compilation goes fine when running **make** as root

**error output when running with sudo make** :

```
make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M= modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-39-generic'
make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_32.tbl', needed by 'arch/x86/include/generated/uapi/asm/unistd_32.h'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [arch/x86/Makefile:248: archheaders] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-39-generic'
make: *** [Makefile:4: all] Error 2
```

$(PWD) command seems to fail, resulting in an error.
I would appreciate if someone can please help understand or any insights that would be really helpful. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Your `sudo` is configured to clean up the environment before running the command it’s given; `PWD` is cleared before `make` runs.

To change this, you can ask `sudo` *not* to clean up the environment:

```
sudo -E make
```

(if the configuration allows this) or manually provide the `PWD` value:

```
sudo make PWD="$PWD"
```

It should also be possible to change the Makefiles to use Make’s own “current directory” variable, `CURDIR`:

```
all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(CURDIR) modules
```